# Colorbox - Click event on Ipad/ Iphone not firing

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I use Colorbox to show an inline form with jquery. But on Ipad and iPhone, the submit button is not working.

I tried to set `{cursor: pointer}` and I also tried to use the touchstart Event and to set `Z-Index to 99`.
But nothing works for me.

On Windows with Chrome and Android, everything works fine.

Does someone have another solution?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show your code, expected behaviour and observed behaviour. As it is now this question lacks details to be answerable and is liable to get closed.

Comment: I believe on tablets and mobile devices you have to handle `touchstart` or `touchend` events.  `touchend` more likely as a finger may still be in the way on `touchstart`

Comment: Also: have you looked [here?](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/faq/)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution... I use Asp.net 2.0 and the form validation code was not generated automatically for the new safari browsers. So, if I called Page_ClientValidate() inside the code before closing the modal form, the button click function stopped working.

After editing the browser caps for the safari in Asp.net now everything works fine again!

Thanks for your help!